# JS export excel file - File corrupted

Tags: javascript, excel, file

I'm having trouble exporting an excel file that's being generated in my NETCORE 3.1 server.

I have to do a POST request to it.

Here is the code

JS:

```
function exportRelatorio(tabela) {

var data = JSON.stringify(tabela);


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "/Relatorios/ExportRelatorio/",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (result) {
        var blob = new Blob(
            [result],
            { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64," }
        );

        // Programatically create a link and click it:
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = "circuitos.xlsx";
        a.click();
    
    },
});
```

}
Server Code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ExportRelatorio([FromBody] string data)
        {
            var relatorios = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Relatorio>>(data);
            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            string fileName = "GestãoCircuitos-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx";
            try
            {
                using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Relatórios");
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Data";
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value = "Matricula";
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 3).Value = "Condutor";
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 4).Value = "Rota";
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 5).Value = "Distância Ideal";
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 6).Value = "Kms";
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 7).Value = "Diferencial";
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 8).Value = "Desvio (%)";
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 9).Value = "Tempo de Condução";
                    for (int index = 1; index <= relatorios.Count; index++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cell(index + 1, 1).Value = relatorios[index - 1].Data;
                        worksheet.Cell(index + 1, 2).Value = relatorios[index - 1].Viatura;
                        worksheet.Cell(index + 1, 3).Value = relatorios[index - 1].Condutor;
                        worksheet.Cell(index + 1, 4).Value = relatorios[index - 1].Rota;
                        worksheet.Cell(index + 1, 5).Value = relatorios[index - 1].DistanciaIdeal;
                        worksheet.Cell(index + 1, 6).Value = relatorios[index - 1].Kms;
                        worksheet.Cell(index + 1, 7).Value = relatorios[index - 1].Dif;
                        worksheet.Cell(index + 1, 8).Value = relatorios[index - 1].Desvio;
                        worksheet.Cell(index + 1, 9).Value = relatorios[index - 1].TempoConducao;
                    }
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                        var content = stream.ToArray();
                        return File(content, contentType, fileName);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View();
            }
    }
```

It gives me a file corrupted message when I open the downloaded file.
The excel error message says excel cannot open the file because the format or extension are not valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

`$.ajax` [doesn't seem to be able](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) to deal with binary data.

You might want to try the [`fetch()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) with native blob support instead.

Also, I added some cleanup here.

```
async function exportRelatorio(tabela) {
    const resp = await fetch("/Relatorios/ExportRelatorio/", {
        body: JSON.stringify(tabela),
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
    });
    if(!resp.ok) throw new Error("Not OK");
    const blob = await resp.blob();
    // Programatically create a link and click it:
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = "circuitos.xlsx";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {  // Clean up
        URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
        a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: it gives me this Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
    at exportRelatorio (site.js?v=5xX4gJKPY3gfDGyOLiFigwQFjBCzZVADmZpcWj30iSQ:59)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Relatorios:1)

Comment: Oops, I forgot `method: 'POST'`.

Comment: Almost there, now my argument in the server side, data, comes null ..

Comment: can you help,please?

Comment: Can you see your browser still posting the data in your browser's inspector?